# How do I fix PytestAssertRewriteWarning?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm just starting out with `pytest` and `pytest_mysql` and have the following code:

```
import pytest
from pytest_mysql import factories

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pytest.main([r'test.py', '-v'])
    testdb = factories.mysql('testdb')
```

This generates a warning:

```
PytestAssertRewriteWarning: Module already imported so cannot be rewritten: pytest_mysql
```

1. Should I be concerned?
2. How can I ensure I don't get the warning?

Comment: Generally pytest is invoked directly, at the command line, e.g. `pytest path/to/my/tests`, so it isn't necessarily clear what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @JaredSmith - I was just following the guidance here: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#calling-pytest-from-python-code. I want to  run the module from VS Code

Comment: @hoefling - I'm not sure what you mean? Pretty new to Python and coding in general. Do you mean install ```pytest_mysql``` somewhere else?

Comment: @Jossy I understand that tutorial exists, *most* python command line utilities have an import option for more exotic edge cases, but it is in no way intended for normal use by total beginners. You want to follow the official tutorial [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/3.0.1/overview.html). VSCode has an [integrated terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal), just run your tests from that.

Comment: @JaredSmith - afraid you're dealing with a total beginner here but I do know about the integrated terminal :-) I see the command line as rather annoying as you have to keep typing out the scripts/commands you want. However, if all the arguments are in something like ```pytest.main([r'test.py', '-v'])``` I can hit the play button and it runs the script. Anyhow, I've given the terminal a try and simply added ```from pytest_mysql import factories``` into a script file. I then ran ```python pytest_mysql.py``` but I get ```ImportError: cannot import name 'factories' from 'pytest_mysql'```.

Comment: @Jossy you'll have to google that error or ask another question about it. But as for typing stuff out, I type *at least* a hundred commands into the terminal per working day, and I type out the entire thing by hand precisely never. You can look through your command history with the up and down arrows, you can autocomplete with tab, and you can use a shell (like fish) or shell plugins (like the zsh autocomplete plugins if you are on e.g. MacOS catalina) to give you predictive autocomplete.

Comment: I think I'll wait to see if anyone else has some suggestions to solve this from the original code. I'm using it absolutely fine with normal ```pytest``` tests. Only getting issues with ```pytest_mysql```

Comment: @Jossy you will *never* become a programmer, for any reasonable definition of programmer, if you don't become reasonably comfortable with using the command line on at least the platform you primarily develop for. Every piece of documentation you read will assume that you know the basics, most of the tools are primarily command line tools (e.g. pylint, mypy, pytest, pip), etc. And if you don't want to be a programmer, why are you programming? Especially with unit tests? Fortunately, it's not that difficult. If you've made it this far, you're certainly smart enough to figure it out.

Comment: @Jossy I did a quick look in `pytest` code. Disregard my above comment, you won't get rid off the warning if you have to import stuff from `pytest_mysql` plugin. Question is whether you can refactor the code so you don't have to call `pytest.main` in the first place - what do you intend to do with `testdb` later? Maybe this code can be moved into a fixture/hookimpl.

Answer (score 2):

### This is how i solved it!

```
import pytest
if __name__=='__main__': #Note 1
    pytest.main()
#
#Your code goes here
#
from pytest_mysql import factories
testdb = factories.mysql('testdb')
```

So try running pytest.main() before you import anything else..

**Note 1**

That's not the usual way you call `__name__=='__main__'`, but as it works i buy it!